# sftp-server accept root, and reject everyone else

Tags: ssh, sftp

I would like to have the `sftp-server` respond only for user `root`.  For all other users, I would like SFTP requests to respond as if `sftp-server` was not configured, i.e. it should return `Connection reset by peer`.

In pseudo-code:

```
  if (protocol == "SFTP")
    if (user == "root") then
      permit access to sftp-server/internal-sftp
    else
      reject: connection reset by peer
    endif
  endif
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Probably not, because your client first needs to negotiate and establish a session before it can send a username to the server. Only after the username has been received the server can reject it and I don’t think the default response, something along the lines of “username and/or password  refused” is an error that can be configured. Allowing only a specific username sftp access is of course possible

Comment: What's the goal behind this request? The service is not hidden (accepts username) and custom handling a critical phase as the login is hardly more secure than the widely tested usual method.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  @HermanB, how would I configure a specific username (root in my case) to be the only one that has sftp access?

Comment: @Paolo.  I am working on an embedded system where no user, other than root, has access to the filesystem.  I was hoping that sftp-server might also have a way that supports that.  What I found is that enabling sftp-server opens the filesystem to non-root users, and that is no acceptable.